# Update .profile in /etc in UNIX

Tags: shell, quoting, prompt

How can i append the following text in .profile in folder /etc/security of UNIX OS?

`PS1='hostname -s':$LOGNAME'[$PWD]'`

i tried:

`print 'export PS1='hostname -s':$LOGNAME'[$PWD]'  '  >> profile`

my output gives:

`export PS1='hostname -s':$LOGNAME[/etc]`

with [/etc].

Comment: Are you sure you want to? What is the final result you are after? Don't you want to use something like `PS1="$(hostname -s):$LOGNAME[$PWD]"` instead?

Comment: Hi terdon, i got your idea also, i use this and now it works  `echo  "PS1=\$(hostname -s):\$LOGNAME'[\$PWD]'"`  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you posted makes little sense. If you read it somewhere, read more carefully. It's very likely that `'hostname -s'` should in fact be `` `hostname -s` ``, i.e. with backticks rather than single quotes. When dealing with computers, punctuation often matters a lot. `` `hostname -s` `` can also be written `$(hostname -s)`, and should be written this way (the syntax with backticks was the first to appear historically but is deprecated because it is less regular).

Text inside single quotes is interpreted literally. Text inside backticks or `$(…)` is a [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution): it is replaced by the output of the command.

So that line should be

```
PS1=$(hostname -s):$LOGNAME'[$PWD]'
```

This sets your prompt to be the name of the machine, a colon, your user name, and the current working directory inside brackets.

You should not edit a file under `/etc` — this applies to all users, and if you need to ask here, then you should not edit this kind of settings for all users. You should set `PS1` in your shell configuration file, which is probably the file `.kshrc` in your home directory (assuming that your shell is ksh — if your shell is bash, use `.bashrc`; if your shell is zsh, use `.zshrc`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape $PWD, probably by writing \$PWD instead. As you do not give context like what shell you are using I cannot say for sure. In bash the correct command would be

```
echo "export PS1='hostname -s':$LOGNAME'[\$PWD]' " >>profile
```

Comment: Hi Thorsten, i am using bash, but when i tried to print or echo it in a file the result gives me something like:

Comment: Hi Thorsten, i am using bash, i tried this and now it works: `echo  "PS1=\$(hostname -s):\$LOGNAME'[\$PWD]'"`  Thanks for the help